# Simple Auth0 for Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, auth0

I have a Heroku application, built in React, that I would like to provide simple password protection for. I do not need to provide registration to new users. Just access for 3 or 4 whitelisted developers while we work on this website.

I added Auth0 as an add-on in Heroku.

Here is the problem. The Auth0 documentation is so overcomplicated that I am not sure how to provision it. And I am unfamiliar with the Auth0 ecosystem. This is so simple. Yet, it is so hard.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Did you look at the quickstart documentation for React SPAs? https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react

Comment: Yes. I have walked through the steps a number of times. But it is written for people who are familiar with the process. For example, it gives code but doesn't say were to put it. I have asked support. They just tell me to look at the documentation.